# Exclude redirection to subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have redirected all urls to the new domain as

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://abc.xyz.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However I want to exclude some subdomains like

```
http://dev.xyz.com etc
```

from being redirected to `http://abc.xyz.com`

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RewriteCond`, which is described at the Httpd Wiki.

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond